# Exercise 4.5.35 of David Marker's Model theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

So I've been doing some exercises in Marker's Book, and I came across this particular exercise on expanding a saturated model $M$ of cardinality $\kappa$.

Let $L^*$ expand $L$ and $M$ a saturated $L-$structure. The author enumerates $(\phi_\alpha : \alpha < \kappa)$ of $L^*_{M}$- sentences, and gives a sketch of the proof in form of exercises. But I'm having some trouble understanding his hint for part **b.)**, namely

"Show that if $\phi_{\alpha}$ is $\exists v\ \psi(v)$" and $T_\alpha + \{\phi_\alpha\} + T + Diag_{el}(M)$ is satisfiable, then for some $a\in M$, $T_\alpha + \{\phi_\alpha, \psi(a)\} + T + Diag_{el}(M)$, is also satisfiable."

For those who might not have the book, $T$ here refers to a $L^*$-theory, and $T_\alpha$ is some theory that is consistent with $T + Diag_{el}(M)$. Now in his hint, the author says:

"Let $A\subset M$ be the parameters from $M$ occuring in $T_\alpha + \{\phi_\alpha\}$ , and let $\Gamma(v)$ be all the $L_A$-consequences of $T_\alpha + \{\phi_\alpha, \psi(v)\} + T + Diag_{el}(M)$. Show that $\Gamma(v)$ is satisfiable and hence, by saturation, must be realized by some $a \in M$"

Edit: I realized I made a mistake in my proof in satisfiability of $\Gamma(v)$ Hence I will rephrase my question explicitly as follows:

1.) How do I proceed to show that $\Gamma(v)$ is satisfiable
2.) Why is it that if $\Gamma(v)$ is satisfiable, then by saturation we get that it must be realized by some $a\in M$.

Any help or insight to shed some light is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: The question "where does saturation come into play here?" is answered by the explicit appeal to saturation in the hint: $\Gamma(v)$ is satisfiable (in some model), so by saturation, it is realized by some $a\in M$.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you solved the exercise, but you don't think you used saturation in your proof, and you want to know whether your proof is correct. I don't think it's possible to give a more helpful answer than I did in my previous comment unless you tell us your argument.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, so it turns out I made a mistake in my original proof; so now I understand the hint even less. I updated the question to reflect this, any help or insight you give is appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\mathcal{L}^*_M$-theory $T_\alpha\cup \{\phi_\alpha\}\cup T\cup \text{Diag}_{\text{el}}(\mathcal{M})$ is satisfiable, so it has a model $\mathcal{N}$. Since $\mathcal{N}|_{\mathcal{L}}\models \text{Diag}_{\text{el}}(\mathcal{M})$, we may assume $\mathcal{M}\preceq \mathcal{N}|_{\mathcal{L}}$. And since $\mathcal{N}\models \phi_\alpha$, $\mathcal{N}\models \psi(b)$ for some $b\in N$.

Let $A\subseteq M$ be the set of parameters from $\mathcal{M}$ occurring in formulas in $T_\alpha\cup \{\phi_\alpha\}$. Since $|T_\alpha| < \kappa$, $|A|<\kappa$. Let $p(x) = \text{tp}_{\mathcal{L}}(b/A)$. Since $\mathcal{M}$ is $\kappa$-saturated, $p(x)$ is realized in $\mathcal{M}$ by some $a\in M$.

It remains to show that the $\mathcal{L}^*_M$-theory $T_\alpha\cup \{\phi_\alpha,\psi(a)\}\cup T\cup \text{Diag}_{\text{el}}(\mathcal{M})$ is satisfiable. By compactness, it suffices to show that for any formula $\chi(a,\overline{c})\in \text{Diag}_{\text{el}}(\mathcal{M})$, where $\chi$ is an $\mathcal{L}_A$-formula and $\overline{c}\in M\setminus A$, the partial $\mathcal{L}^*_A$-type $T_\alpha\cup \{\phi_\alpha,\psi(x)\}\cup T\cup \{\chi(x,\overline{z})\}$ is satisfiable.

We have $\mathcal{N}\models T_\alpha\cup \{\phi_\alpha\}\cup T$. Interpreting $x$ as $b\in N$, $N\models \psi(b)$. And $\exists \overline{z}\, \chi(x,\overline{z})\in \text{tp}(a/A) = \text{tp}(b/A)$, so there is some tuple $\overline{c}'\in N$ such that $N\models \chi(b,\overline{c}')$. Interpreting $\overline{z}$ as $\overline{c}'$, we are done.

Note that I presented the argument here in a (superficially) different way than in Marker's hint. Rather than considering the set $\Gamma(v)$ from the hint, I took a witness $b$ in the elementary extension $\mathcal{N}$ and considered the complete type of $b$ over $A$. I think this approach makes the compactness argument at the end a bit clearer.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This really helps. Also Im looking through some post here and found that you also answered one of them. I posted a follow up question regarding it; if you could look at it I would also be grateful, thanks. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3680956/follow-up-on-the-existence-of-prime-model/3680992#3680992

Comment: @user16319 it seems Noah Schweber has given you a good answer there.